# Mathematical Representation of the Generator of Translation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Where does this expression come from? Why is the $N$ an exponent?

$J(\Delta x' \hat x) = lim_{N \to \infty} (1-\frac{ip_x\Delta x'}{N\hbar})^N $

Comment: where did you get that formula from? did you read it in a book? which one?

Comment: Modern Quantum Mechanics by Sakurai & Napolitano (page 46, 2nd Edition)

Comment: Through binomial expansion that expression can be shown to be the exponential function as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  So it is $e^{i p_x \Delta x /\hbar}$.  See answers to this q: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900921/the-definition-of-e-by-limits-of-11-nn-through-series-expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider the expression

$$
e^{\alpha D}f(t) = f(t + \alpha) \tag{1}
$$

where $D$ is the derivative operator. Eq. (1) states that the operator $D$ generates translation in the coordinates. You can find the justification for this expression [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185354/exponential-of-the-differential-operator). Now, also recall that

$$
e^{\alpha D} = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{\alpha D}{N} \right)^N
$$

and that the representation of momentum in coordinates space is $p = -i\hbar D$, putting everything together you get that the operator

$$
P(\alpha) =  \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{i\alpha p}{N\hbar} \right)^N
$$

generates displacements on the coordinates

$$
P(\alpha)\psi(x) = \psi(x + \alpha)
$$

Comment: Is there a name for the second expression?

Comment: @Math12345 It is just a property of the exponential, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function)